# Catel framework - replace view

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, catel

I'm building application with multiple modules. Each of module contains a viewmodel and view.

I would like to create solution, for automatically show SelectedModule in a part of my application.

Assume that I have MainWindow view like this:

```
<catel:UserControl
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:catel="http://catel.codeplex.com" xmlns:dxsch="http://schemas.devexpress.com/winfx/2008/xaml/scheduler"
    xmlns:dxe="http://schemas.devexpress.com/winfx/2008/xaml/editors"
    xmlns:dxg="http://schemas.devexpress.com/winfx/2008/xaml/grid"
    x:Class="OrchestraCatel.Views.MainWindow">

  <DockPanel LastChildFill="True">
    <ContentControl x:Name="Ribbon" DockPanel.Dock="Top">
<!--      My Ribbon-->
    </ContentControl>
    <ContentControl x:Name="MainView" DockPanel.Dock="Top">
<!--      My Main Page-->
    </ContentControl>
  </DockPanel>
</catel:UserControl>
```

And I would like to show a UserControl specified in another DLL inside `MainView` ContentControl after Ribbon item click.

Both, Ribbon Button and MainView view are in module DLL

I had an idea to include `SelectedViewModel` inside my `MainPage` ViewModel, and then, create DataTemplates for each ViewModel, but this solution will break my vision of Modules, which should be independent.

Is there a way in Catel to replace a view with another one? From anywhere?

Answer (score 0):

I think Prism solves this issue for you. Please take a look at the integration of Prism with Catel:

https://catelproject.atlassian.net/wiki/display/CTL/Catel.Extensions.Prism